# Secure Site Backend URL with Random Key and NGINX

Tags: security, nginx, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) and [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/).

I want to secure the site's Backend Signin url with a random generated key and NGINX sites-available.

The only way to get to the Signin page is use the secure key in the url or bookmark it.

---

#### Secure Key

I have this code which worked with Joomla when using the `/administrator` path.

Though OctoberCMS uses [/backend/backend/auth/signin](https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/173#issuecomment-43571766).

```
if ($http_referer !~ "^/backend/backend/auth/signin"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($args !~ "^vhXmdqLx1lkNQ46f5egC"){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/.*backend/backend/auth/signin/? /404 redirect;
}
```

It works on the Signin page, but once logged in  it redirects to 404, because other pages in `/backend` are not included in the code.

---

#### Wildcard

I tried adding a wildcard (*) to the uri like this, but it gave the same 404 result:

```
if ($http_referer !~ "^/backend/backend.*"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($args !~ "^vhXmdqLx1lkNQ46f5egC"){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/.*backend/backend.*/? /404 redirect;
}
```

---

Notes:

- The secure key is just an example I generated, not the real key.
- Trying `/backend` instead of `/backend/backend` ruined the
  backend's css url's, because the css links in the html were requiring the secure key.

Comment: Did you try to change the config key `backendUri ` ? in your cms.php file?

Comment: @OsDev I did not know to check there. I've now replaced the backendUri '/backend' with the key. Now I won't have to use nginx for this task. Thanks for the info.